# Merge several tuples in python list

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

I'm currently trying to merge a few tuples in a list. Here is what I have so far

```
dates = [(u'13', u'01', u'19:00', u'Event 1', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'06', u'02', u'10:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'07', u'02', u'09:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'24', u'02', u'20:00', u'Event 3', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'25', u'02', u'19:30', u'Event 4', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'8', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'9', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'10', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'27', u'04', u'20:00', u'Event 6', u'1', u'', u'')]

prev_name = None
prev_day = None
counter = 1
newList = []

for value in dates:
    if prev_name is None and prev_day is None:
        prev_name = value[3]
        prev_day = value[0]
    else:
        if not value[2]:
            if prev_name == value[3] and int(value[0]) == (int(prev_day) + 1):
                prev_name = value[3]
                prev_day = value[0]
                counter += 1
                newList.append((value[0], value[3], counter))
                continue
            else:
                prev_name = value[3]
                prev_day = value[0]
                counter = 1
                newList.append((value[0], value[3], counter))
                continue
    newList.append((value[0], value[3]))

for value in newList:
    print value
```

The list I get looks like this:

```
(u'13', u'Event 1')
(u'06', u'Event 2')
(u'07', u'Event 2')
(u'24', u'Event 3')
(u'25', u'Event 4')
(u'8', u'Event 5', 1)
(u'9', u'Event 5', 2)
(u'10', u'Event 5', 3)
(u'27', u'Event 6')
```

What I'm trying to do is to Merge this 3x tuples where I have added the counter at the end.
But not in a normal merge way.
I want to remove all but the first entry, but also move the counter to it.

So

```
(u'8', u'Event 5', 1)
(u'9', u'Event 5', 2)
(u'10', u'Event 5', 3)
```

Should become

```
(u'8', u'Event 5', 3)
```

I already got the list to add the counter at the end if this is a reoccuring event. But struggle to merge this into one tuple list entry.
This is for a ical export, where instead of doing one entry for each day, it should create a single entry, but with +x days length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically grouping event wise with first occurrence of event and no. of times event has occurred syntax [(first_date_of_occurrence, Event, No. of times Event Occurred),..]. If my guess for your requirement is correct following code should work:

```
from itertools import groupby

dates = [(u'13', u'01', u'19:00', u'Event 1', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'06', u'02', u'10:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'07', u'02', u'09:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'24', u'02', u'20:00', u'Event 3', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'25', u'02', u'19:30', u'Event 4', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'8', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'9', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'10', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'27', u'04', u'20:00', u'Event 6', u'1', u'', u'')]

def accumulate(l):
    for key, group in groupby(l, key=lambda x:'%s:%s' % (x[3],x[2])):
        event_occurence = 0
        date_occurence = None
        for i, data in enumerate(group):
            if i == 0:
                date_occurence = data[0]
            event_occurence+=1
        yield (date_occurence, key.split(':')[0], event_occurence)

print list(accumulate(dates))
```

output:

```
[(u'13', u'Event 1', 1), (u'06', u'Event 2', 1), (u'07', u'Event 2', 1), (u'24', u'Event 3', 1), (u'25', u'Event 4', 1), (u'8', u'Event 5', 3), (u'27', u'Event 6', 1)]
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after. It also preserves the order. I now have a total on every event, but that is ok. I can see Event 2 has been untouched. So it only works for Events with no Time, and where the Name match, right?

Comment: Ok, just tested with the resulting ical. As with the above data, Event 2 should have 2x entries. But with the grouping on the name results in 1. It should only group if there is no time set, e.g. data[2]

Comment: kindly provide desired output with respect to given example

Comment: Taking the same data, output should be: `[(u'13', u'Event 1', 1), (u'06', u'Event 2', 1), (u'07', u'Event 2', 1), (u'24', u'Event 3', 1), (u'25', u'Event 4', 1), (u'8', u'Event 5', 3), (u'27', u'Event 6', 1)]`

Comment: just fondle with key of group-by like key=lambda x:'%s:%s' % (x[3],x[2]). Code modified as per requirements. Hope future changes can be done by u :)

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better now. I just never used, or better knew, about groupie, or how to use it. I should be ok from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
dates = [(u'13', u'01', u'19:00', u'Event 1', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'06', u'02', u'10:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'07', u'02', u'09:00', u'Event 2', u'0', u'', u''),
         (u'24', u'02', u'20:00', u'Event 3', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'25', u'02', u'19:30', u'Event 4', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'8', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'9', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'10', u'04', u'', u'Event 5', u'1', u'', u''),
         (u'27', u'04', u'20:00', u'Event 6', u'1', u'', u'')]

clear_data = [[l[0], l[3]] if l[2] else [l[0], l[3], None] for l in dates]

new_data = {}

for event in dates:
    if event[3] not in new_data:
        new_data[event[3]] = [event[0]]
        if not event[2]:
            new_data[event[3]].append(1)
    else:
        if not event[2] and len(new_data[event[3]]) > 1:
            new_data[event[3]][1] += 1
        else:
            new_data[event[3]].append(event[0])

result = []

for event, data in new_data.items():
    if any(isinstance(x, int) for x in data) and len(data) > 1:
        result.append((data[0], event, data[1]))
    else:
        for value in data:
            result.append((value, event))

print result
```